# Gravity form desplegable

Tags: php, html, wordpress

hay alguna forma de con el **plugin gravity form**, hacer que cuando se seleccione un campo tipo Drop Down aparezcan nuevos campos. 
Ejemplo: Drop down de seleccion de DNI o CIF. Cuando selecciono DNI que aparezca un campo de introduce DNI, y cuando selecciono CIF que ponga: introduce el nombre de tu empresa( y que se elimine o oculte "seleccionar dni".

¿Es posible esto con este plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Es posible sin necesidad de tener que usar otro plugin, podés usar los conditional logic:

http://www.gravityforms.com/features/conditional-logic/

Creas tu dropdown con las opciones y la visibilidad del resto de los campos la manejas desde los seteos condicionales.